# Should I use "was" or "is" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice, tense, past-tense

Should I use *was* or *is* in this sentence?

> I asked them if Person X **was/is** in any way related to or affiliated with their organization at any time.

My guess is "at any time" warrants "was". Is this correct?

Answer (score -1):

You are correct.  "Is" would be about now.